# Custom error message in login template in auth middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I've grouped certain routes that require the user to be logged in before they perform some action.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
      Route::get('/posts/create', 'PostController@create');
});
```

Now when the user visits this url, he'll be redirected to the login page if the user is not logged in. But I want to display a custom error message saying *you've to be logged in to perform this action* in an error block.

Where can I pass the custom message to the login view before redirecting?

Note: I know it's obvious that if the user lands on the `create post` page with a login form, it indicates that the user should login. Still, that error form is `required`.

Answer (score 0):

When you're redirecting add `with()` clause to [flash](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#flash-data) a message to the session:

```
return redirect()->with('message', 'You've to be logged in to perform this action');
```

In 5.2 you may want to override one of the login related methods (it depends on what you're trying to achieve) in the `Auth\AuthController.php`. In 5.3 do the same in the `Auth\LoginController.php`

Comment: I'm using the inbuilt auth middleware, where do I modify in that?

Comment: Try to do that in `app\Http\Middleware\Authenticate` middleware.